# will Windows 10 be activated if installed on a laptop that used to have it preinstalled, from an external medium like a DVD or flash?

Tags: windows, installation, windows-10, recovery

I accidentally wiped-clean my Toshiba Satellite's hard drive, including the recovery partition and the preloaded Windows 10 that was stored on it. Now, the only option I believe I have is to download the ISO, burn it to a DVD or flash, boot the laptop from it and install Windows 10.

If so:

- Will Windows 10 be automatically activated ?
- Will Windows detect the laptop is one with preloaded copy of Windows and as such license it automatically ?

I don't have any product activation code, the only code printed on the laptop floor is the laptop's serial number...

Thanks.

Comment: Wrong site; you want Super User.  But yes, it is my understanding that this will just work.

Comment: I hope it will. Super User you say..? I'm checking that out, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Anecdotally, the same thing just happened to me.  I deleted all partitions and re-installed it completely fresh on a Dell Latitude laptop, figuring I'd lost the license.

In my case, the laptop is licensed just fine.  I didn't do anything specific to license it.

As a side note, The ISO I downloaded didn't specify version, though it defaulted to Windows 10 Professional before when I used it on a custom-built machine.  This one defaulted to Windows 10 Home, something I also didn't specify.  I don't remember for sure which version I had before I nuked it.

Comment: Thanks. ..yeah, it seems like the license is bound to the hardware itself or something.. . I installed Windows 10 and it was automatically licensed, without me doing anything.. .